# Get Dell KACE to run a script outside of the normal interval

Tags: deployment, patch

Is it possible to get Dell KACE to run a script on a client machine immediately when some condition happens?

I need the script to run on the agent machine within 1 minute of the condition happening (like a file appearing). This is because I need an application to update to a newer version only when a user action happens.

If I set the inventory interval very low and use a custom condition it might affect the general performance of KACE, since there are many client machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to do this.

I can send an inventory via the API even without admin rights. But the inventory checks/results cannot be linked to scripts in KACE, so that gets me nowhere.